# Converting Numeric format to YYYY Date in R

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have a dataset imported from a CSV file, where the "Year" column starts from 2001 going on until 2013.

The column class however, is 'integer'.

```
> class(Year)
[1] "integer"
```

I have looked at various solutions and posts on how to make this change, but the solutions seem to be for some version of `YYYY-mm-dd`/`dd-mm-yyy`/`mm-dd-yyyy` or to convert something like `20150521` to a date.

These are some of the commands I have tried so far, with no luck.

```
Year <- as.Date(Year, "%Y")
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

as.Date(Year)
Error in as.Date.numeric(Year) : 'origin' must be supplied

as.Date(Year, Year[1])
Error in as.Date.numeric(origin, ...) : 'origin' must be supplied

as.Date(Year, "2001")
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

as.Date(Year, 2001)
Error in as.Date.numeric(origin, ...) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

How can I convert a column in just the YYYY format, to a date?

Comment: You got very close -- `strptime(as.character(y), "%Y")`

Comment: a "year" by itself is not a `Date` object in R. It needs at least day granularity. So you'd need to turn any 4-digit, valid year integer into `####-##-##` to get it to be a `Date` object.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.
My dataset shows annual trends, so there is no granularity with respect to months or days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### There is no way of having a date object without including a day and a month.

Even if you write:

```
strptime(as.character(y), "%Y")
```

This include a day and a month:

```
strptime(as.character(1999), "%Y")
[1] "1999-10-07 EEST"
```

As a workaround you can try keeping the year as it is or including the **first day for each year** and *extract the year* whenever you want to, like this:

#### base-r:

```
date <- strptime("2012", "%Y")
format(date, "%Y")
[1] "2012"
as.numeric(format(date, "%Y"))
[1] 2012
```

#### lubridate:

```
require(lubridate)
year(date)
[1] 2012
```